# Are periodic tilings stable against defects outside of some region away from the defect?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, tiling

Suppose that I have a set of Wang tiles on a 2D infinite grid, and that normally the tiling pattern is periodic. Assume it has period $p$ in both vertical and horizontal direction. Then at fixed points on the lattice, I remove the tile/introduce a defect. Is there any notion of the periodic tiling recovering its structure sufficiently far away from the defects?

There appears to be a similar result for types of aperiodic tilings. Here it's is shown that a Robinson tiling is stable with respect to defects: https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~miekisz/stablejsp.pdf

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you mean something like, if you pick a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then as $r \to \infty$, the distance (with the tiling metric) between the translated defected tiling $\mathcal{T}_{defect} - rv$ and the hull of the original periodic tiling tends to zero? That is, $$\lim_{r \to \infty}\inf\{d(\mathcal{T}_{defect} - rv, \mathcal{T} + w) \mid w \in \mathbb{R}^2\} = 0$$? If that's your question, then the answer is clearly yes for only finitely many defects.

Comment: Something like this. More like, if I take a point (or set of points) with defects, then how far away from the defects do I have to go before the tiling is guaranteed to be a translation of the defect-free tiling. I assume that at some point away from the tiling should reconstitute itself. Though any references are appreciated -- I'm try to prove a physics result and this field is entirely new to me. None of the papers I can find have a similar result, so presumably it's either trivial or not true.

Comment: If your tiling has a defect then any translate of that tiling will still have defects, just far away from the origin. All you can hope for is that the defects appear arbitrarily far away from the origin and that there is a *sequence* of translates of the tiling (each with defects) whose *limit* is defect-free. This is true for any periodic tiling (or indeed repetitive tiling) with finitely many defects (or in fact tilings with arbitrarily large 'defect-free patches')

Comment: Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but I think I'm thinking about this in a different way. Take your empty tiling grid, and now choose a set of points and the grid and label them defects. These points have the property that they can match with any tiles regardless of the tiling rules? I now want to place a Wang tiling on the lattice. Can I say that, if I take an $n\ times n$ section of the grid sufficiently far away from the defects, this $n \times n$ section is identical to a translation to a tiling with no defects? I can draw a diagram if this isn't clear (apologies!).

Comment: Alternatively, consider putting a tiling defect at the origin. Now suppose that I cut out the $k \times k$ area centred around the origin (i.e. consider the grid $L$, now consider $L - k^2$). Is there a $k$ for which if I remove the area around the origin, the remaining grid has zero distance away from a translation of the defect-free case?

Comment: ah ha, I think this question is much more difficult! So you want some kind of 'self correction' of the set of wang tiles. It's a good question but I don't know an answer. Perhaps consider sending an email to Jarkko Kari, who is an expert on Wang tilings.

Comment: Exactly! Perfect -- I'll drop him an email. I saw some of his papers on similar topics. Thanks loads!

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, you are asking:

> Suppose we have a finite set of Wang tiles, which have a periodic tiling $T$ of the plane. Now, fix the colors on finitely many grid squares, such that the result can still be extended to a tiling of the plane. Can this extension can be chosen such that the tiling is identical to $T$ up to a translation, except for finitely many errors near the defect?

The answer to this question is "no". Consider the eight Wang tiles given by rotations of the following two tiles:

[image]

Observe that in any tiling of these, the green squares must be matched up, so we are using domino shapes with certain matching conditions. The resulting dominoes look like this, up to rotation:

[image]

where the grey circles indicate a side that can be either red or blue, whichever we choose.

After some thought, it should be clear that the only restriction this imposes on a domino tiling is that no two dominoes can be aligned edge-to-edge, with their union forming a $2\times 2$ square. Note that every arrangement of these Wang tiles uniquely determines a squarefree domino tiling of the plane, and every squarefree domino tiling yields at least one corresponding arrangement of the Wang tiles.

First, note that these tiles have a periodic arrangement:

[image]

(I've shown the domino tiling, but it should be obvious how to convert this into a periodic arrangement of the Wang tiles.)

On the other hand, suppose that we start off with a domino configuration like this:

[image]

Then it is not too hard to verify that the unique squarefree domino tiling containing this arrangement looks like:

[image]

But no translation of this latter tiling will ever line up with our periodic one! So we cannot place Wang tiles beyond those original eight in a way that reverts to our original periodic tiling. (In fact, we only need to fix three of them for this behavior to occur.)